# keyboard does not appear, facebook sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, ipad

i am having a problem, i want to call the facebook sdk, so i can post from my app. When I was calling the dialog for the login from a pushed view it was ok, but now i am showing a view using presentModalViewController and from that view i want to call the facebook login dialog. but now the keyboard does not appear. i didn't change anything just the way i present the view. do you have an idea what can be happening ?

I am using splitview controller, from the detail view (that is modaly presented) i call the facebook sdk what should be wrong ?

Comment: I have same issue in pushed view.

Answer (score 1):

in ur application delegate's function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions add the following Code

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]
```